# Is it possible to host a WebService inside a Compact Framework application (like Nancy)

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, nancy

I am developing a Compact Framework application for use on Windows CE (with Visual Studio 2008)

Now I want to control the app via a rest interface.

The first thing that comes to my mind is nancy. However I haven't found anything about nancy being CF compatible. Has anyone more information about this?

Or is there another way to achive this?

Comment: Did you try compiling it yet under compact framework?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other frameworks...

But Nancy will not work with Compact Framework. Its pretty much non-existent now isn't it?

The last release was in 2009 so it doesn't support any of the .NET features required to run Nancy.

Which I would have to assume means it cannot support anything like WebAPI/MVC/ServiceStack or basically anything.

At most you're probably going to be subjected to hosting a basic asmx service.

Comment: `Its pretty much non-existent now` - That's not true, Windows CE is pretty big in the embedded sector. That's why Microsoft just released Compact Framework 2013 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee486593.aspx alongside with Windows Embedded
Compact 2013 and Visual Studio 2012 support. Anyway, it is still mostly .NET 3.5 based so I need a something that will run as a thread within my app and allow some basic webservice communication.

Comment: So 3.9 actually did get released in the end? Wikipedia shows is still as Unknown Release date. Possibly look at an older version of ServiceStack, that may run since SS3 still targets .NET 3.5